# What is the cost of Wild Dragonhide Agile Breastplate?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor, pricing, special-materials

Agile Breastplate: 400
Masterwork: 150
Dragonhide: 550 (double cost)
Wild: 9000 (+3)

Total: 11000

Is my math right?

What about for fullplate?

Fullplate : 1500
Masterwork: 150
Dragonhide: 3300 (double cost)
Wild: 9000 (+3)

Total: 12300

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big deal here is that magic armor must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus before magic armor special abilities can be added to it. (That is, as per [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/), "A suit of armor with a special ability must also have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.") This increases the price of both armors substantially.

## That agile breastplate…

- An [agile breastplate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/agile-breastplate/) has a price of 400 gp.
- A masterwork agile breastplate has a price of 550 gp.
- My reading of the special material [dragonhide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment-/special-materials#TOC-Dragonhide) is that armor made from it is already masterwork therefore a dragonhide agile breastplate has a price of 1,100 gp, double that of the masterwork agile breastplate, and it counts as masterwork.
- Magic armor must have a magic enhancement bonus of at least +1 before magic armor special abilities can be added to it, so **a *+1 [wild](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/wild/) dragonhide agile breastplate* has a price of 17,100 gp**. That is, 1,100 for the nonmagical-but-alread-masterwork dragonhide agile breastplate plus 16,000 gp for the magical +1 enhancement bonus and the magical virtual +3 enhancement bonus of the magic armor special ability *wild*.

## …and that suit of full plate

- [Full plate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/full-plate/) has a price of 1,500 gp.
- Masterwork full plate has a price of 1,650 gp.
- Dragonhide full plate has a price of 3,300 gp.
- *+1 wild dragonhide full plate* has a price of 19,300 gp.